# Taking Value from Database and Create XML FILE VIA C#

Tags: c#, xml

Well I produce code which takes the values from the database and creates XML files, but I stack on how to modify my code in order to avoid the empty cells from the column VALUES,  also I need to select the data from the column VALUES where the column SELECT is 1. Can you please help me with examples? Thank you in advance .

code

```
    public DataSet produceFieldsXml(int langID, int presID)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["beta"].ConnectionString;


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT IsubField.ID,IsubField.SUBJECT_ID as SUBJECTID,IsubField.VALUE AS DSCR,IsubField.FIELD_TYPE_ID, PFTT.VALUE AS TITLE
                                                  FROM I_SUBJECT_FIELD  IsubField, P_FIELD_TYPE_TITLE PFTT
                                                  WHERE IsubField.PRESENTATION_ID = " + presID + @"
                                                        AND IsubField.LANGUAGE_ID = " + langID + @" 
                                                        AND PFTT.FIELD_TYPE_ID = IsubField.FIELD_TYPE_ID 
                                                        AND PFTT.LANGUAGE_ID = " + langID + @" 
                                                 ORDER BY IsubField.SUBJECT_ID", con);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "FieldItem");

        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("SEQ", typeof(Int64));

        DataSet dsNew = new DataSet();

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter daII = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM I_SUBJECT WHERE ID = " + Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SUBJECTID"].ToString().Trim()) + "", con);
            DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
            daII.Fill(dsa, "FieldItem");

            dsNew.Merge(dsa);
        }

        DataSet dsaa = new DataSet();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter daII = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT SEQ FROM P_CATEGORY_FIELD WHERE CATEGORY_ID = " + Convert.ToInt32(dsNew.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CATEGORY_ID"].ToString().Trim()) + " AND FIELD_ID = " + Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FIELD_TYPE_ID"].ToString().Trim()) + "", con);
            daII.Fill(dsaa, "FieldItem");
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SEQ"] = dsaa.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SEQ"];                        
        }

        for (int i = 0; i > dsaa.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SEQ"] = dsaa.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SEQ"];         
        }

        dsaa.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + "ZipFiles\\" + "new.xml");

        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: Please always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @SonerGönül - although I agree with that as generic rule, in this particular example there are just integers and you can hardly hack an integer type.

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @PeriklisEleftheridis - I'm not sure I understand your question correctly; can you elaborate more on this.  Are you looking for something like SELECT ... ISNULL(Value,0) instead of SELECT ... Value  ?

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar I am Looking something Like this. Select From "Table" data where Values(Column) is not null and Select(column) is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd really try to learn more SQL, because I'm pretty sure those three queries above can be one query given the right joins. Unfortunately we cannot help you right now, unless you show us what I_SUBJECT_FIELD, P_FIELD_TYPE_TITLE, I_SUBJECT and P_CATEGORY_FIELD look like and how they're related.

Because this is simply very bad:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    SqlDataAdapter daII = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM I_SUBJECT WHERE ID = " + Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SUBJECTID"].ToString().Trim()) + "", con);
}

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    SqlDataAdapter daII = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT SEQ FROM P_CATEGORY_FIELD WHERE CATEGORY_ID = " + Convert.ToInt32(dsNew.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CATEGORY_ID"].ToString().Trim()) + " AND FIELD_ID = " + Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FIELD_TYPE_ID"].ToString().Trim()) + "", con);
}
```

Those queries get executed numerous times and at most they should be executed once (bit trickier in the second case, but not impossible), and in fact they really should be part of the main query (provided the tables are set up correctly).

An even bigger headscratcher is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i > dsaa.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SEQ"] = dsaa.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SEQ"];         
}
```

...since that is exactly the same line as in the previous for-loop.

Once you manage to create a single query it will be far easier to convert that data into XML.

Also look into [encapsulating code in using statements](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheUsingStatementIsBetterThanASharpStickInTheEyeAndASqlConnectionRefactoringExample.aspx).